# TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined at VueComponent.filterKategori (app.js:16260)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

this is my code

```
computed: {
    filterKategori() {
      var kategori = this.kategori.data.filter(f => {
        return f.induk == null && f.id_klasifikasi == this.id_klasifikasi;
      });

      return kategori;
    }
  },
```

and this is my structure data

```
kategori: {
    current_page: 1
    data: [{id: "01", nama_kategori: "Karya Umum", reorder: 6, ishide: "0", id_klasifikasi: "01", induk: null},…]
    first_page_url: "http://localhost:8002/api/fetch/kategori?page=1"
    from: 1
    last_page: 1
    last_page_url: "http://localhost:8002/api/fetch/kategori?page=1"
    next_page_url: null
    path: "http://localhost:8002/api/fetch/kategori"
    per_page: "10"
}
```

can't anyone help me please, why the filter is'nt working and the error says this cannot read property filter of undefined

Comment: Is `data` inside `kategori`? Bc from your json I can't tell exactly. If it's outside you have to do `this.data.filter`

Comment: yes, the data is inside kategori

Comment: Where is `kategori` placed on your Vue elem? It should be in a `data: function () { return { kategori: { } } }` in order to work

Comment: kategori is placed on :  
`data() { 
return{
kategori: []
}
}` @RaulRene

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in one of the requests you get "null" instead "this.kategori.data" and the filter is called as a property (legacy reasons in ECMAScript more https://2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html) More about "null": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

u need add additional check on "data" property:

```
computed: {
    filterKategori() {
      if(!this.kategori.data) return kategori;

      var kategori = this.kategori.data.filter(f => {
        return f.induk == null && f.id_klasifikasi == this.id_klasifikasi;
      });

      return kategori;
    }
  },
```